# Gracefully handle DoubleRenderError / is it possible to "throw out" previous renders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails app has a global rescue method in application_controller which catches any errors and displays a nice looking 500 page.

This works for most exceptions, but I can't find a way gracefully handle a DoubleRenderError. It does not seem possible to render the nice 500 page because attempting to do so will throw a new DoubleRenderError from within the global rescue method.

Does anybody know of a way to "throw out" previous renders so I can render the 500 page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to structure your code so that this type of error is impossible - how are you managing to get 2 renders in the same action?